# Double Lost Of Precision

Tags: java, double

I'm a little bit confused because I lose precision all the time.

Maybe I'm operating with the wrong type. I have a String like "100.00". But when I do

> Double.parseDouble("100.00") it is being cut off to 100. Need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not losing precision. That's just formatting differently.

Comment: It's probably not being cut off but left out when printing because it doesn't add information. Besides that as Kayaman already stated, it's not a loss of precision. A loss of precision would be something like 161.0 * 0.7 = 112.69999 instead of 112.7.

Comment: In binary, what do you imagine is the difference between `100` and `100.00` (in a `double`)?

Comment: You are converting a ``String``, which includes "human-readable precision", into a ``double``. A ``double`` does not have a "precision", as it is always as precise as it can be. If you want to display the ``double`` value as a ``String``... That's where you'll need to include a "precision" again.

Comment: Could you tell us how you are coming to the conclusion that `100` and not `100.00` is not stored in the variable?

Comment: Like in mathematics, there is absolutely no difference between 100.00 and 100. It is just the same number.

Answer (score 4):

You probably printed your number with `System.out.println(d)`. It will internally call `Double.toString(double)`, whose specification states

> How many digits must be printed for the fractional part of m or a? There must be at least one digit to represent the fractional part, and beyond that as many, but only as many, more digits as are needed to uniquely distinguish the argument value from adjacent values of type double.

This is because the `double` number has no notion of "decimal precision". It is a *binary* number with fixed *binary* precision (number of binary digits after the binary point).

Comment: In PostGreSql Database it is being saved as "100" and not "100.00"

Comment: In what type of field? Because if it's not a string field, the difference between 100 and 100.00 isn't real since they are two representations of the same real number.

Answer (score 0):

Just use BigDecimal instead of Double like this:

```
BigDecimal houndred = new BigDecimal("100.00").setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

BigDecimal does not loose precision at all. Additionally you can set scale, precision and rounding mode as you prefer.